# ¿Como se puede realizar scraping en una pagina web que tiene javascript con python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola quisiera saber como puedo realizar el scraping de una pagina web que tiene Javascript usando PyQt5, la pagina de la que quiero extraer informacion es esta:
https://www.tumangaonline.com/biblioteca/mangas/22954/Sonomono-Nochi-Ni

De esta pagina quiero sacar el nombre de la serie y los capitulos.
Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from urllib.request import urlopen


class Render(QWebPage):


    def __init__(self, html):
        self.html = None
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().setHtml(html)
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.html = self.mainFrame().toHtml()
        self.app.quit()


url = 'https://www.tumangaonline.com/biblioteca/mangas/22954/Sonomono-Nochi-Ni'

source_html = urlopen(url)

rendered_html = Render(source_html.read()).html

soup = BeautifulSoup(rendered_html, 'lxml')

p = soup.find_all('a')

print('title is %r' % soup.select_one('title').text)
print(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

No he probado tu codigo pero tengo bastante experiencia haciendo scraping con BeautifulSoup y parece que vas bien.

El problema es que cuando la pagina tiene javascript y es dinamica cuando haces el request a la pagina la informacion aun no esta en el html.

Para resolver eso lo primero que suelo hace es mediante Postman Interceptor intercepto las solicitudes mientras accedo normalmente con el navegador a la pagina donde esta la informacion.

Luego de eso identifica la solicitud hecha con javascript o ajax que retorna la informacion que quieres y una vez identifiques el la solicitud replicala tu mismo con python bien sea con urlopen o requests.

Una vez lo consigas extrae la informacion de la respuesta de dicho request con BeutifulSoup u otra cosa.

Comment: Hola José García te agradecería mucho si me pudieras dar un ejemplo, el código que puse arriba es de un ejemplo que encontré en internet y adapte para la probar el scraping a esta pagina.

Comment: Bueno me tome un poco de tiempo para revisar y bueno al parecer la tienes bastante facil ya que esa pagina funciona con un API.

Cuando entras a ella se llaman a estos dos endpoints que contienen la informacion que quieres.

https://www.tumangaonline.com/api/v1/mangas/22954

https://www.tumangaonline.com/api/v1/mangas/22954/capitulos?page=1&tomo=-1

Puedes hacer el request con python a esos endpoints y re retornaran toda la informacion que necesitas en un json del cual es super sencillo obtener los datos.

Comment: Hola como puedo encontrar esos endpoints en una pagina web, para saber como poder identificarlos y poder aprender mas sobre el scraping.