# scrapping python, no puedo obtener la clase id soup.select('')

Tags: html, python, css3, scraping

Abre en el navegador los enlaces de la página, pero no encuentro las id principal para todas las demás id de los links

```py
import requests, webbrowser, bs4
print('Searching...')
res = requests.get('https://www.mismarcadores.com/futbol/chile/primera-division/resultados/')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
>#Aqui va class id de la pagina pero no consigo obtener el id correcto del html porque ? o como se trabaja con este tipo de paginas
linkElems = soup.select('')  
numOpen = min(20, len(linkElems))
for i in range(numOpen):
    urlToOpen = 'https://www.mismarcadores.com/partido/' + 
    linkElems[i].get('id')    
    print('Opening', urlToOpen)
    webbrowser.open(urlToOpen)
```

Comment: Hola @Fscode, Bienvenido a *Stack Overflow en Español*. ¿Quieres obtener los links de la página?

Comment: Siiii, porfa tu tienes experiencia porfa que pasas debo seguir

Comment: Estuve leyendo tu código, y revisando la página. donde dice /partido/, ¿Qué es lo que realmente quieres hacer?, sospecho que clickear un partido y ver los detalles en la página que se abre. Sí lo que quieres hacer es esa simulación, lo recomendable sería usar [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: cada link de cada partido jugado tiene un id entonces yo quiero es obtener los id desde la pagina html y agregar a la direccion https : // www.mismarcadores.com / partido /   +   id

Comment: Porque no uso selenium porque es un simulador de click, y este es un codigo de inicio a un scraping, pero me topo con esta barrera, que el html no es normal como otras paginas donde si funciona el codigo

Comment: Fscode, el problema es que no puedes capturar la información que deseas de ese modo, ya que cuando haces el requests.get, la información aún no está en la página porque es generada mediante javascript. En este enlace, una solución alternativa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95496/como-se-puede-realizar-scraping-en-una-pagina-web-que-tiene-javascript-con-pyth

Comment: voy a intentar con selenium porque otras opciones no se como hacerlos si alguien tiene algun manual video tutorial o algo que diga hagalo paso a paso seria maravilloso, si alguien hace un manual seria excelente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando `Selenium`

Para obtener tener los partidos que muestra la página principal puedes hacerlo de esta manera:
`find_elements_by_css_selector` : Devolverá una lista de `WebElements`. Si usas `find_element` (Devolverá la primer coincidencia que se encuentre en la página).

Cuando trabajo con `clases` que contienen nombres con espacios, como `event__match event__match--static event__match--oneLine`. Suelo usar `css_selector` anteponiendo un `.` al iniciar el nombre de la `clase` y relleno los espacios con `.` .

Entonces para obtener todos los elementos haría:

```
 aux_ids = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.event__match.event__match--static.event__match--oneLine')
```

Ahora podemos iterar sobre esta lista de `WebElements`:

Vamos a mostrar los partidos que muestra la página:

```
for aux in aux_ids:
    print("*"*100)
    print(aux.find_elements_by_css_selector('.event__participant.event__participant')[0].text,
          aux.find_element_by_css_selector('.event__scores.fontBold').text.replace('\n',''),
    aux.find_elements_by_css_selector('.event__participant.event__participant')[1].text)    


****************************************************************************************************
O'Higgins 1 - 3 U. Española
****************************************************************************************************
Curicó Unido 1 - 0 Colo Colo
****************************************************************************************************
Audax 0 - 1 Palestino
****************************************************************************************************
U. De Chile 1 - 1 Coquimbo
****************************************************************************************************
La Serena 3 - 0 S. Wanderers
****************************************************************************************************
Everton 0 - 1 U. La Calera
```

Ahora en vez de mostrarlos, podemos guardarlos en una `lista` y vamos a guardar el bendito `id` que necesitábamos:

```
partidos = []    
for aux in aux_ids:
    partidos.append([aux.find_elements_by_css_selector('.event__participant.event__participant')[0].text,
                     aux.find_element_by_css_selector('.event__scores.fontBold').text.replace('\n',''),
                     aux.find_elements_by_css_selector('.event__participant.event__participant')[1].text,
                     aux.get_attribute('id')])
```

En este momento tenemos una `lista` con los partidos y su resultado (en el momento que cargó la página). 
Ahora por comodidad creo un `DataFrame` con la `lista de listas` que tenemos (esto es a gusto de cada uno).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(partidos)
df.rename(columns={0:'local',1:'resultado(PARCIAL)',2:'visitante',3:'id'},inplace=True)
```

Ahora nos falta borrar de `id` *(ej: 'g_1_StNsW7lf')*, el prefijo `g_1_` para poder tener la url del partido.

Hay varias opciones para hacer esto, lo normal sería hacer [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation):

```
 df['id'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x:x[4:])
```

Si por alguna razón le agregan un prefijo distinto '*g_10_*', esta forma no nos estaría sirviendo, por eso otra opción puede ser haciendo `split` de `'_'`. 
De esta manera nos devuelve :`[g, 1, StNsW7lf]`, y estaríamos tomando el elemento de la posición 2.
y lo haríamos de la siguiente manera:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x:x.split('_')[2])
```

Y finalmente podemos dar de alta una nueva columna con el link del partido, donde tenemos que agregar el link `'https://www.mismarcadores.com/partido/'`:

```
url_aux = 'https://www.mismarcadores.com/partido/'

df['link'] = url_aux + df['id']
```

Ahora si mostramos nuestro `DataFrame`:

```
local     resultado(PARCIAL)    visitante   id          link
O'Higgins      1 - 3            U. Española StNsW7lf    https://www.mismarcadores.com/partido/StNsW7lf
Curicó Unido   1 - 0            Colo Colo   YsUYXTJs    https://www.mismarcadores.com/partido/YsUYXTJs
Audax          0 - 1            Palestino   WYs7xABQ    https://www.mismarcadores.com/partido/WYs7xABQ
U. De Chile    1 - 1            Coquimbo    M3MoVR30    https://www.mismarcadores.com/partido/M3MoVR30
La Serena      3 - 0            S. Wanderers    M3fL0bzl    https://www.mismarcadores.com/partido/M3fL0bzl
```